# I have some issues with my crawler in php

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

my crawler isn't working. I want it to output

```
<div class="content">
```

But when i run it i get this output:

> Array ( )

This is my code:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML('https://www.google.com/');

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class,"content")]');

$result = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $result[] = array($link->getAttribute("innerHTML"), $link->nodeValue);
}
print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadHTML()` parses the HTML from the **string** that you pass it, see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). In your case the string is `https://www.google.com/` which is obviously not valid HTML.

You could use cURL to retrieve the actual HTML from the page. I made a few quick tests and seems that Google's response varies with the user agent, so you could use a real one, e.g.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36');
$html = trim(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
// rest of the code
```

Comment: It only gets the first match, how do i get all matches?

Comment: The code that you have does return all matches. If I run the XPath query on Chrome's developer console it returns a single element. Keep in mind that what you see in the developer console might be different than what cURL returns due e.g. DOM generated dynamically via Javascript.

Comment: sorry, i was echoing it as $var[0][1] :|thanks for your help!